# How to get the confidence interval around the variable importance generated by randomForest?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, random-forest, importance

Using randomForest in R is it possible to get a variance or confidence interval around the importance of a variable (% difference in mean square error)?

From the randomForest package

```
set.seed(4543)
data(mtcars)
mtcars.rf <- randomForest(mpg ~ ., data=mtcars, ntree=1000, keep.forest=FALSE,
                          importance=TRUE)

importance(mtcars.rf, type=1)
```

> ```
> %IncMSE
> cyl  17.061579
> disp 19.020929
> hp   18.195448
> drat  6.677707
> wt   17.858616
> qsec  5.849071
> vs    5.467722
> am    3.933137
> gear  5.129811
> carb  8.332738
> ```

```
varImpPlot(mtcars.rf)
```

[image: Variable Importance Plots]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In principle, permutation score (MeanDecreaseAccuracy/MeanIncreaseMSE) is an average over trees, so there is also standard deviation over trees; `randomForest` stores it in the `importanceSD` element of the model and uses when executing `importance` with `scale=TRUE`.

However, experiments show that the assumptions required to use this value for any parametric reasoning are violated in practice (see [this](http://www.statistik.uni-dortmund.de/useR-2008/slides/Strobl+Zeileis.pdf) for an overview), thus it is not a good idea to plot confidence intervals based on this.

So, if you wish to make some statistically significant claims about the importance order of attributes I would recommend doing a bootstrap and plotting boxplots of importance over iterations (possibly with notches).

And if you wish to establish a threshold between relevant attributes and noise, you really want to do feature selection, a task that will be done better by some feature selection algorithm than by visual judgement.

Comment: +1 I would also suggest to have a look at the `Boruta` package, that does exactly feature selection and statistical relevance assessment